# Raspberry Pi3 Bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, pi-3

I just got my Raspberry Pi3 and installed Bluetooth

`sudo service bluetooth status` shows

```
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2016-03-12 13:48:57 AEDT; 44s ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 2285 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─2285 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd
```

I am planning to use a bluetooth keyboard and mouse.

`hcitool scan` shows `Device is not available: No such device` and `hcitool dev` shows no Devices.

Is there anything else needed to activate the on board bluetooth? I recollect reading that there are no drivers yet, but cannot find this again. Some users seem to indicate that they have it working.

---

**EDIT**
I just found the reference (in MagPi 43) and installed `pi-bluetooth`. I can now scan and see my wireless mouse.

Unfortunately I can't seem to find how to connect to the Pi.
Any help welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easyest way is to start the GUI and Install a program called bluedevil and using its wizard to configure it.

Comment: I was initially put off by the reference to KDE, but after failing to connect to my Apple Wireless Keyboard with Bluetooth Manager (there did not seem to be any option to enter a passkey), devided to give this a go. It took quite a while to install, and after the event could not find. From the `Run` menu I found `bluedevil-wizard`, which I ran, and successfully connected my keyboard.

Answer (score 4):

My mouse is now working.

Unfortunately I cannot exactly describe the process, as it was a bit trial and (mostly) error.

I finally gave up on the command line, and started the GUI.
There was a bluetooth icon on the Panel which describes itself as:-

```
blueman-applet
1.99.alpha1
Blueman is a GTK based Bluetooth manager
```

This applet found my Bluetooth mouse and offered many options (The ¨Setup New Device¨ did not work and either wanted my mouse to enter a passcode or failed).
I did manage to add my device, and then a sub-menu enabled me to connect.

The following were installed. The 1st is probably not necessary as I assume ¨pi-bluetooth¨ would have this as a dependency.

```
apt-get install bluetooth
apt-get install pi-bluetooth
apt-get install blueman
```