# Unable to link Bluetooth keyboard to Pi 3

Tags: bluetooth, keyboard, pi-3

I have enabled Bluetooth on my Pi 3 and connected phone and laptop successfully. When I try to connect my Apple or Logitech keyboard it says failed to connect on pairing. I've tried via terminal and UI. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I also struggled with this, but finally got my Apple keyboard to connect. See the following

[Raspberry Pi3 Bluetooth](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/43947/raspberry-pi3-bluetooth)

I installed `bluedevil`. It took quite a while to install, and after the event could not find. From the Run menu I found bluedevil-wizard, which I ran, and successfully connected my keyboard.